# How do I get all users via relationship in loop

Tags: php, laravel

I have a collection of likes. Each like has a belongs to ->user relationship.
        How do i get all users. Currently I'm only gettting one user.

```
$likes = Like::where('thought_id', $thoughtComment->thought_id)->where('comment_id', $thoughtComment->id)->where('like_flag', 1)->get();


        foreach($likes as $like){
            $users = $like->user->username ?? '';
        }

        return $users;
```

Comment: `$users[] = $like->user->username ?? '';` - don't forget to initialise the array before the loop.  You may also prefer to omit users without a username - but thats up to you.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: I also wouldn't forget to eager load that relationship to drop the n+1 problem this loop has. `Like::with('user')->where('thought_id....`

Answer (score 1):

Alright.  Let's start with where you have:

```
$likes = Like::where('thought_id', $thoughtComment->thought_id)->where('comment_id', $thoughtComment->id)->where('like_flag', 1)->get();
    foreach($likes as $like){
        $users = $like->user->username ?? '';
    }

    return $users;
```

Next let's fix what you have to build an array, rather than keep overwritting the same scalar value.

```
$likes = Like::where('thought_id', $thoughtComment->thought_id)
    ->where('comment_id', $thoughtComment->id)
    ->where('like_flag', 1)->get();
$users = array(); //Users needs to be an empty array.

foreach($likes as $like){
    $users[] = $like->user->username ?? ''; // We append to it.
}

return $users;
```

But we can do better than that because this will perform nested queries.  So let's load the users into the like with `with` which we could loop through.

```
$like = Like::where('thought_id', $thoughtComment->thought_id)
    ->where('comment_id', $thoughtComment->id)
    ->where('like_flag', 1)
    ->with([ // Eager the relationships we'll use
        'user' => function($query){
             $query->select('user.username'); 
             //But really, we only need the username
        }
    ])->get();

foreach($likes as $like){
    $users[] = $like->user->username ?? ''; // We append to it.
}

return $users;
```

Then use the collection's flatten and pluck functions so we don't have to write the loop at all.

```
$like = Like::where('thought_id', $thoughtComment->thought_id)
    ->where('comment_id', $thoughtComment->id)
    ->where('like_flag', 1)
    ->with([
        'user' => function($query){
          $query->select('user.username');
        }
    ])->get();

//Lets get rid of the loop altogether and let the collection do the work.
$users = $like->flatten()->pluck('username');
```